# How to improve performance of PC, upgrade processor, memory or clock speed?

Tags: performance, memory, clock, processor

A PC has a microprocessor which processes 16 instructions per microsecond. Each instruction is 64 bits long. Its memory can retrieve or store
  data/instructions at a rate of 32 bits per microsecond.
Mention 3 options to upgrade system performance. Which option gives most improved performance?

And the answer provided is

a) upgrade processor to one with twice the speed

b) upgrade memory with one twice the speed

c) double clock speed

(b) gives most improved performance.

Overcoming the bottleneck of a PC can improve the integrated performance.

However, my problem is that I am not sure of why b gives the most improved performance. Additionally, would a and c give the same performance? Will it provide the same performance? Can it be calculated? I am not sure of how these different parts would work on the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question's leading paragraph contains the necessary numbers to see why it's **b)**:

The CPU's processing rate is fixed at 16 instructions per microsecond. So an instruction takes *less than a microsecond* to execute.

Each instruction is 64 bits long, but the memory system retrieves data at 32 bits per microsecond. So it takes **two** microseconds to retrieve a single instruction (i.e. 64 bits).

The bottleneck is clear: it takes longer to retrieve an instruction (2μs) than it does to execute it (1/16thμs).

If you increase the CPU speed (answer **a)**), the CPU will execute an individual instruction faster, but it will still be waiting idle at least 2μs for the next instruction to arrive, so the improvement is wasted.

To eliminate bottlenecks you need to increase the memory-system's speed to match the CPU's execution speed, so the memory needs to read 64 bits in a 1/16μs (or 32 bits in 1/32μs).

I assume answer **c)** refers to increasing the speed of some systemwide master clock which would also increase the CPU and Memory data-rates. This would improve performance, but the CPU would still be slaved to the memory speed.

Note that your question describes a simplistic computer. Computers were like this originally, where the CPU accessed memory directly, instruction-by-instruction. However as CPUs got faster, memory did not - so computer-engineers added cache levels: this is much faster memory (but much smaller in capacity) where instructions (and data memory) can be read as fast as a CPU can execute them, solving the bottleneck without needing to make all system memory match the CPU's speed.